# Montserrat Issues

Tags: typefaces, opentype, typekit

I need to use Montserrat for a client and when I change the typeface in Photoshop, it appears to be Montserrat Alternates. I have deactivated ALL Adobe fonts and installed Montserrat from multiple sources, such as Font Squirrel and Google Fonts. They appear correct in the TTF preview as well as when I install them into Font Book. But when I go to select the font in Photoshop, it is very clearly the "fancy" version called Montserrat Alternates.

Things I tried that did not work:

- Installed and used a font management program — Fontbase.
- Uninstalled ALL versions of Montserrat from Font Book, emptied my trash, and checked to see if the font was located in the Library font folder to ensure there isn't a weird font lingering somewhere.
- Deactivated ALL Adobe fonts. I really think they are the culprit somehow.

Note: ONE version I downloaded worked, but it is the "regular" weight and I need light and bold to also work, but haven't had any success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately tech support, which this is, is off topic. You'll have better luck on SuperUser.com -- FYI, you may need to clear adobe font caches (google that)

Comment: It's maybe annoying that I ask, but did you try to deactivate all Adobe fonts, reboot the computer (in case CC somehow remembers anyway), install the wanted font and then open Photoshop and try to use it?